# Is there a Gitlab API Call for "Tests Tab" under Pipeline?

Tags: api, gitlab, documentation, gitlab-api

I need to get the content of the tests tab, but I didn't find one for that.

Unfortunatelythe response of
/gitlab/api/v4/projects/{projectId}/pipelines/{pipelineId}
doesn't return the tests tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being the tests tab, check if the data returned by the "[pipeline’s test report](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#get-a-pipelines-test-report)" includes what you need:

```
GET /projects/:id/pipelines/:pipeline_id/test_report
```

```yaml
{
  "total_time": 5,
  "total_count": 1,
  "success_count": 1,
  "failed_count": 0,
  "skipped_count": 0,
  "error_count": 0,
  "test_suites": [
    {
      "name": "Secure",
      "total_time": 5,
      "total_count": 1,
      "success_count": 1,
      "failed_count": 0,
      "skipped_count": 0,
      "error_count": 0,
      "test_cases": [
        {
          "status": "success",
          "name": "Security Reports can create an auto-remediation MR",
          "classname": "vulnerability_management_spec",
          "execution_time": 5,
          "system_output": null,
          "stack_trace": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```